# Print different entries into a single line(listbox, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a planner where in the user inputs their date, time and their plan and want them to print into a single line but I'm getting errors and it's not working.

I'm not so sure about the use of classes if it's correct or wrong but that's the  output that i want to achieve where it's formatted to that way.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class planner_start:
    kind='plan'
    def __init__(self,plan,time,date):
        self.plan = plan
        self.time=time
        self.date=date

def planner_save(self):
    return"March {} 2019: {}- {}".format(self.date,self.time,self.plan)

def course_save():
    listbox.insert(tk.END, planner_save(a))


def get_list(event):
    # get selected line index
    index = listbox.curselection()[0]
    # get the line's text
    seltext = listbox.get(index)
    # delete previous text in enter1
    enter.delete(0, 50)
    # now display the selected text
    enter.insert(0, seltext)


def delete_item():
    try:
        index = listbox.curselection()[0]
        listbox.delete(index)
    except IndexError:
        pass
def save_list():
    # get a list of listbox lines
    temp_list = list(listbox.get(0, tk.END))
    # add a trailing newline char to each line
    temp_list = [chem + '\n' for chem in temp_list]
    # give the file a different name
    fout = open("courselist.txt", "w")
    fout.writelines(temp_list)
    fout.close()

    exit()
def set_list(event):
    try:
        index = listbox.curselection()[0]
        # delete old listbox line
        listbox.delete(index)
    except IndexError:
        index = tk.END
    # insert edited item back into listbox1 at index
    listbox.insert(index, enter.get())
def quit_code():
    exit()

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Calendar Planner")
window.configure(background='#ABD1B5')
window.geometry("720x360")


title=tkinter.Label(window,text='Calendar Planner', fg="#054A29", bg="#5BBA6F",
                    font=("American Captain", 24))
title.config(width=100)
title.grid(row=0)
title.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="center")
title.grid_propagate(False)


title=tkinter.Label(window,text='Your plans for this month', fg="#054A29", bg="#5BBA6F",
                    font=("American Captain", 18))
title.config(width=24)
title.grid(row=0)
title.place(relx=.3, rely=.23, anchor="center")
title.grid_propagate(False)

listbox = Listbox(window)
listbox.pack()
listbox.config(width=50)
listbox.grid(row=0)
listbox.place(relx=.1,rely=.5,anchor="w")


#Enter Date
date_input = ttk.Label(window,text='Enter Date',background='#355834', font=("Market Deco",12),
                     foreground='#FFFFFF', width=15, anchor='center')
date_input.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=5)
date_input.place(relx=.73, rely=.37, anchor="e")

dateName = tkinter.StringVar()
date_entry = ttk.Entry(window, width=15, textvariable = dateName)
date_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
date_entry.place(relx=.88, rely=.37, anchor='e')

#Enter Time
time_input = ttk.Label(window,text='Enter Time',background='#355834', font=("Market Deco",12),
                     foreground='#FFFFFF', width=15, anchor='center')
time_input.grid(row=4,column=2, padx=5)
time_input.place(relx=.73, rely=.47, anchor="e")

timeName = tkinter.StringVar()
time_entry = ttk.Entry(window, width=15, textvariable = timeName)
time_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)
time_entry.place(relx=.88, rely=.47, anchor='e')

#Enter Plan
plan_input = ttk.Label(window,text='Enter Plan',background='#355834', font=("Market Deco",12),
                     foreground='#FFFFFF', width=15, anchor='center')
plan_input.grid(row=4,column=2, padx=5)
plan_input.place(relx=.73, rely=.57, anchor="e")

planName = tkinter.StringVar()
plan_entry = ttk.Entry(window, width=15, textvariable = planName)
plan_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)
plan_entry.place(relx=.88, rely=.57, anchor='e')


#Button for course
btn = ttk.Button(window, text='Add Plan', command=course_save)
btn.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
btn.place(relx=.72, rely=.67, anchor='center')

#Button quit
btn = ttk.Button(window, text='Exit', command=quit_code)
btn.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
btn.place(relx=.9, rely=.9, anchor='center')

#Button delete
button4 = tk.Button(window, text='Delete selected line     ', command=delete_item)
button4.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
button4.place(relx=.2, rely=.9, anchor='center')

#Button save
button2 = tk.Button(window, text='Save lines to file', command=save_list)
button2.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
button2.place(relx=.4, rely=.9, anchor='center')

enter = tk.Entry(window, width=45, bg='yellow')
enter.insert(0, 'Click on a plan to edit then press enter to update')
enter.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
enter.place(relx=.3, rely=.77, anchor='center')
# pressing the return key will update edited line
enter.bind('<Return>', set_list)
# or double click left mouse button to update line

listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', get_list)


a=(date_entry.get(),time_entry.get,plan_entry.get())
window.mainloop()
```

This is my code above. Please help me because I'm new to python.

Comment: can you check your indentation? Which functions belong to the class `planner_start`?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple errors in your code, and I'm a begginer too. I don't know tkinter, so I can't give full answer (it's better that you copy it from somebody who has it right anyway). But hopefully I can give you some tips:
- Your import is crazy. First you import tkinter so you can use it's name, then you import one single thing from it, then you import it once again by importing everything from tkinter, and as last one import tkinter as tk, so you can use tk as a shortcut for tkinter.
- class should be with paretheses, so `class planner_start():`
- use regular spacing, code is easier to read
- self returns now a tuple, one of a reasons it's not working
- course_save() should be either with indent block and (self), so it belongs to a class, or call inside it should be something like `planner_start.planner_save(a)`
I took a look at the bottom, time_entry.get needs parentheses.

I hope it helps at least a bit.